# Laravel (5.5) - Third party JS libraries in production version

Tags: laravel, npm, leaflet

I'm using third party JS libraries in my Laravel 5.5 project (leaflet and leaflet-draw). I installed the libraries using npm:

`npm install leaflet`

`npm install leaflet-draw`

I added the folowing lines in resources/assets/js/app.js:

`require('leaflet');`

`require('leaflet-draw');`

and in resources/assets/sass/app.scss:

`@import "~leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";`

`@import "~leaflet-draw/dist/leaflet.draw.css";`

after that, I run:

`npm run dev`

Assets compile and my application works fine on my localhost (I run basic laravel server with `php artisan serve`).

I tried deploying this application to server. I deployed it to a subfolder, so the address is: 
https://example.com/laravelapplication

I followed this instruction:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-laravel-application-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04

All routes and urls work fine. I don't get any code errors. But, leaflet and leaflet draw libraries have trouble fetching their icons and fonts. I get these errors:

`GET https://example.com/fonts/vendor/leaflet-draw/dist/images/spritesheet.svg?fd5728f... 404 (Not found)`

`GET https://example.com/images/vendor/leaflet/dist/images/layers.png?a613745... 404 (Not found)`

I'm not sure, but it  looks like the library is searching for fonts and icons in the wrong place. It should look in https://example.com/laravelapplication instead of https://example.com

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Please share your `webpack` file and actual directories for the images and fonts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the actual URL these images are located in once your app is deployed, then a workaround would be to simply hard-code these locations:

For Leaflet, you can use the [`L.Icon.Default`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#icon-default)'s [`imagePath`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#icon-default-imagepath) option: (in your JavaScript)

```js
L.Icon.Default.prototype.options.imagePath =
  "https://example.com/laravelapplication/images/vendor/leaflet/dist/images/";
```

For Leaflet.draw plugin, you have to override the [CSS rules](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/blob/v0.4.14/src/leaflet.draw.css#L25-L36): (in your CSS, make sure it is evaluated *after* Leaflet.draw's CSS)

```css
.leaflet-draw-toolbar a {
  background-image: url('https://example.com/laravelapplication/fonts/vendor/leaflet-draw/dist/images/spritesheet.svg');
  background-image: linear-gradient(transparent, transparent), url('https://example.com/laravelapplication/fonts/vendor/leaflet-draw/dist/images/spritesheet.svg');
}

.leaflet-retina .leaflet-draw-toolbar a {
  background-image: url('https://example.com/laravelapplication/fonts/vendor/leaflet-draw/dist/images/spritesheet-2x.png');
  background-image: linear-gradient(transparent, transparent), url('https://example.com/laravelapplication/fonts/vendor/leaflet-draw/dist/images/spritesheet.svg');
}
```